# Keyboard and Mouse don't work from TAILS screen so can't get to Tor

Tags: tails

I loaded TAILS from a disk and the mouse doesn't work to click yes/no on the initial TAILS screen. The keyboard doesn't work either it seems. Thus, I can't even get to Tor as I can't get TAILS to load. A Debian based operating system runs native on the hard drive on the computer that is trying to run TAILS but I don't think there is native graphics on the mother board ... I think it is an old high end graphics card plugged into the mother board which is a Z68xud-4-b3 Gigabyte and that may be connected to the problem.

Comment: Would your mouse and keyboard be using Bluetooth? The Tails team was [looking for testers](https://mailman.boum.org/pipermail/tails-testers/2014-April/000010.html) as they suspected Bluetooth could be a problem. In any cases, you might want to look on [how to report software errors to the Tails team](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/bug_reporting/index.en.html).

Comment: This question has not seen any clarification, so I'll close it. If you have any additions, please [edit](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/2114/edit) the question and it can be reopened.